# R Studio not displaying inline output data frame (e.g. header, tail...)

Tags: r, rstudio

my R Studio does not display inline output with function such like header, tail. The screenshot is attached below. 
[image]
The first six rows of my data frame should show at the inline output.
[image]
I have tried several R and R Studio versions but neither of them worked.

R version: 3.5.1
R Studio version: 1.1.456
Windows 10

Comment: Thanks! But I am working on a Rmd file and both of them are selected.

Comment: I still cannot see the output inline

Answer (score 0):

Fist, make sure you are working in an "R markdown" or "R Notebook" file, not an "R Script" file. Also check (under the gear-icon dropdown) that "Show Previews Inline" and "Chunk Output Inline" are selected.

Then, if those are true, notice that only the results from the **last** executed line of code will show inline.  If you want to see the output of multiple lines of code, you need to put them in different code chunks. As in:

````
```{r}
head(JellyBelly)
```
````

and then

````
```{r}
binom.test(...)
```
````